# How do I install Node-Inspector globally on Redhat's OpenShift and run it?

Tags: node.js, openshift, node-inspector

I cannot find any reference on the net or at OpenShift as to how to install npm modules globally. I want to install Node-Inspector globally, as stated in their docs. When I ssh in to my OpenShift Node.js gear and run "npm install -g Node-Inspector" I get the very unexpected "npm ERR! 404 'Node-Inspector' is not in the npm registry". When I run that command with sudo, OpenShift returns the expected: Permission denied.

Running either of those 2 commands on my Mac does install the Node-Inspector module.

What is the OpenShift's intended design method to install npm modules globally in their cloud environment, so that I can install the Node-Inspector module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is not directly identified here, as per the question, but the solution is here:  https://developers.openshift.com/languages/nodejs/dependency-management.html

Basically, you manually edit the node.js app's package.json on your local development system, adding the node-inspector module.  When you send the app up to your Openshift gear, OpenShift will recognize it as a global module since it had not been installed as a local module and will install it globally.

That solves the install. I have gotten node-inspector to begin, as I see its banner on the command line but it then fails to open the socket for port 5858. But I will make that a new question.